# How do I resolve this error when installing Ruby on a Macbook Pro (Mountain Lion) with RVM?

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

When I attempt installation using

```
rvm install 2.2
```

or

```
rvm install ruby-2.2.4
```

I get the following error when I input `rvm use 2.2` or `rvm use 2.2.4`:

```
ruby-2.2.4 is not installed.

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time. 
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.2.4. Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies. 
Checking requirements for osx_brew. 
Installing requirements for osx_brew. 
Updating system..... 
Installing required packages: openssl....... 
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install openssl', showing last 15 lines of /Users/mikejschorah/.rvm/log/1468093589_ruby-2.2.4/package_install_openssl.log
 ++ case "$1" in ++ [[ -t 1 ]] ++ return 1
 ++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log. Try brew tap --repair` and make sure brew doctor looks reasonable. 
Check Homebrew requirements github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n' 
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log. Try brew tap --repair and make sure brew doctor looks reasonable. Check Homebrew requirements github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation 
++ case "$_system_version" in ++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.`
```

Comment: Please add the output of `rvm install ruby-2.2.4`.

Comment: @Nic Nilov `Requirements installation failed with status: 1.`

Comment: Is this the complete error output?

Comment: `Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.2.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Installing requirements for osx_brew.
Updating system.....
Installing required packages: openssl.......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install openssl',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/mikejschorah/.rvm/log/1468093589_ruby-2.2.4/package_install_openssl.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There...`

Comment: Please add the complete output to your question itself, not as a comment.

Comment: @Nic Nilov `...were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1Requirements installation failed with status: 1.`

Comment: To the question body please, not as comments.

Comment: @Nic Nilov I'm unable to do that. Stack Overflow blocks it because there is too much code in the question. Does anyone else have an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the unformatted error output it can be seen that  rvm cannot install `openssl` which is a requirement for ruby.

Run this command to install it using `brew`.

```
brew install openssl
```